# MySQL Foreign Keys and Performance Impact

Tags: mysql, performance, foreign-keys, innodb

I am designing a new database from scratch at the moment, trying to foresee any issues that may arise as scale increases

I'm making the **login system** at the moment

I have tables: (InnoDB, Dynamic)

- **user**               *(Updates on new user creation, only stores id, email, hash, pepper)*
- **user_profile**       *(Updates on user modifying profile info - it is
  ecom, so irregular)*
- **user_addresses**     *(Updates on user adding an address)*
- **user_reset**         *(Updates on password recovery attempt)*
- **user_attempts**      *(Updates on failed password attempt)*
- **user_devices**       *(Updates on login)*

At present, **all tables have a foreign key of ID from "user" table** - they may or may not have their own ID too depending if it is needed. **"user_profile" also has foreign key of "email" from "user" table**

I also plan to add marketing tables which foreign key from "user" table "id" in the future which will do anything from tracking traffic, to monitoring clicks, etc.

**Will the setup I have perform optimally? Any suggestions of revisions I could make to improve performance? i.e. Do I even need foreign keys? Assistance would be greatly appreciated**

.

**Anticipating Your Questions:**

*Why split user and user_profile?*

I'm hoping for performance gain on login... Maybe not? Not that familiar with foreign keys in all honesty, they have always seemed to hinder more than they help, but I really want to do things "right" from the beginning

*Define "scale"*

100k users on a website, since if it ever got to that size I'm pretty sure I could hire a team of developers lol

Edit: Thanks for -1 without any comment, glad you understand MySQL way better than I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 updates -- not a big deal.  Should be able to handle hundreds of users *per second*.

If any of those tables are "1:1", then consider combining them.  (If they are "1:many", then separate tables is appropriate.)

Indexes are important for performance.  A `FOREIGN KEY` is two things:  an index, and a consistency check.  Many textbooks push for using FKs; I am usually happy with just the equivalent index.